# jquery addClass not executed correctly with "on" (ex live) jquery method and datatables Initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I use the datatables plugin with jquery.
I don't understand why the jquery `addClass` code is executed after the destroy, reinizialitation and sorting of datatables ...

```
$('#added_jobs').on( 'click', '.rem_added', function () {

    $("#gif_loader").addClass("overlay");

    oTabJobs.fnDestroy();       
    loadTabJobs();
    oTabJobs.fnSort( [ [3,'asc'] ] );

    $("#gif_loader").removeClass("overlay");

});
```

Comment: it shouldn't be executed afterwards.  Please describe a little more of what you're seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is the fact that the sort method is locking up page not allowing the DOM to be updated until after the loop has run.

You need to add a slight delay for the DOM to fully update before calling your destroy/sort code.

```
$('#added_jobs').on( 'click', '.rem_added', function () {

    var loaderImg = $("#gif_loader");
    loaderImg.addClass("overlay");

    window.setTimeout( function () {
        oTabJobs.fnDestroy();       
        loadTabJobs();
        oTabJobs.fnSort( [ [3,'asc'] ] );
        loaderImg.removeClass("overlay");
    }, 10);

});
```